# Network Visualization - R code - Which Package is needed?

Tags: r, visualization, social-network-analysis, sequential-pattern-mining

I'm trying to create a network visualization to study the flights to and from a certain airport.

My data consists of 123000 rows in this format:

```
Origin_ID    Destination_ID    Frequency
  1726            3504           40000
  3504            4517              40
  5616            7205              38
               ...
```

I'm trying to create a image similar to this:

[image]

Basically, I want to be able to see the strength of the relationship (based on the frequency) and identify which combinations are most common in that airport.

Can it be created in R using this format? Or do you suggest any other open source platform to create this visualization?

Comment: The igraph package, or the network package. `library(igraph); igraphdemo("cohesive")`

Comment: Igraph in R will help you out with this problem.
Below link might help you. [http://www.kateto.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Polnet%202015%20Network%20Viz%20Tutorial%20-%20Ognyanova.pdf](http://www.kateto.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Polnet%202015%20Network%20Viz%20Tutorial%20-%20Ognyanova.pdf)

Comment: perfect :) exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

The [visNetwork](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/visNetwork/vignettes/Introduction-to-visNetwork.html) R package is the best I've worked with.  It renders with the vis.js Javascript package right in your RStudio window.  Nodes and edge visualization is fully customizable and may be data-driven.  They implement click-functionality on your graphs, so you can rearrange them or highlight a node and its neighbors.  I've found people really enjoy this in presentations, and the highlight functionality is great for making static PowerPoint presentations or figures.